# Replace some characters in a string with the next unicode character

Tags: string, rust, replace

I have an input text as following:

```
 inputtext = "This is a test";
```

I need to replace some of the character (based on a certain criteria) to next unicode character

```
 let i = 0;
 for c in inputtext.chars() {
   if (somecondition){
     // Replace char here
     inputtext.replace_range(i..i+1, newchar);
     // println!("{}", c);
 }
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you might want a custom `Iterator` but it's hard to say for sure without knowing exactly what the criteria and replacement characters are.

Comment: the replacement characters are just the next unicode character. the criteria (somecondition) is a probability.

Comment: Then you can probably just use `inputtext.chars().map(|c| if somecondition { /* replacement logic */ } else { c })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily update a string in-place because a Rust string is not just an array of characters, it's an array of *bytes* (in UTF-8 encoding), and different characters may use different numbers of bytes. For example, the character `߿` (U+07FF "Nko Taman Sign") uses two bytes, whereas the next Unicode character `ࠀ` (U+0800 "Samaritan Letter Alaf") uses three.

It's therefore simplest to turn the string into an iterator of characters (using `.chars()`), manipulate that iterator as appropriate, and then construct a new string using `.collect()`.

For example:

```rust
let old = "abcdef";

let new = old.chars()
    // note: there's an edge case if ch == char::MAX which we must decide
    //       how to handle. in this case I chose to not change the
    //       character, but this may be different from what you need.
    .map(|ch| {
        if somecondition {
            char::from_u32(ch as u32 + 1).unwrap_or(ch)
        } else {
            ch
        }
    })
    .collect::<String>();
```